# Animation is not working properly on some devices - android

Tags: android, animation

I used this animation **blink.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        />
</set>
```

I called it like this to stop it after 5 seconds:

```
mainThreadhanlder.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.startAnimation(blinkAnim);
            }
        });
mainThreadhanlder.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.clearAnimation();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

but the problem is the animation is not working on the downside of the textView: The downside of the 00 can be shown that the animation is not working proporely !

[image]

so, **what can be the source of the problem** ?

Comment: Try including some padding inside your textView in your layout xml file

Comment: ah sorry it worked !!! @L-X added it as solution please

Comment: Sorry what you want , I didn't understand your comment and did padding worked ??

Comment: I create that view programmatically, i did not put padding, after i set padding it worked well, u may post it as answer i mean

Comment: I found that removing `android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"` the animation works properly. If included the text just appears, and disappears without any animating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add Padding In your TextView

```
<TextView
 ...
 android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Comment: Since im adding the view programatically, i added padding by view.setPadding(10,10,10,10);   thank you